# HTML5 + JS video - multiple players each with own controls

Tags: javascript, html, video

My page contains two HTML5 video players - each with their own controller button below using JS.

Both sets of buttons only work with one of the players (the second one) - I know I need to name each player and buttons but I have tried many combos and can't get it to work. Code below…

```
<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <video poster="poster1.png" id="video1" width="90%">
    <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video><br>
     <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button>
  <br><br>
</div> 

<script> 
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1"); 

function myVideo.playPause() { 
    if (myVideo.paused) 
        myVideo.play(); 
    else 
        myVideo.pause(); 
} 
</script> 



<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <video poster="poster2.png" id="video2" width="90%">
    <source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video><br>
     <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button>
  <br><br>
</div> 

<script> 
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video2"); 

function playPause() { 
    if (myVideo.paused) 
        myVideo.play(); 
    else 
        myVideo.pause(); 
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to pass the id you want into the script (so you only need the script to exist once):

```
<script> 
    function playPause(vidId) { 
        var myVideo = document.getElementById(vidId); 
        if (myVideo.paused) 
            myVideo.play(); 
        else 
            myVideo.pause(); 
    } 
</script> 

<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <video poster="poster1.png" id="video1" width="90%">
    <source src="trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video><br>
  <button onclick="playPause('video1')">Play/Pause</button>
  <br><br>
</div> 

<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <video poster="poster2.png" id="video2" width="90%">
    <source src="trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video><br>
  <button onclick="playPause('video2')">Play/Pause</button>
  <br><br>
</div>
```